# Dynamic RBAC configuration in Spring boot security

Tags: spring, security, boot, rbac

I am currently using spring boot 2.3.0 RELEASE version.

I have my roles and permissions stored in database. When the application launches, I have a SecurityCobfig file that extends WebsecurityConfigurerAdapter to load all the permissions and load this data to HttpSecurity object.

Code snippet of my WebsecurityConfig class

http.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers(HTTP.GET, "/employee/fetch/*).hasRole("USER");

Here I get the API and role details from database.

If I change the permission of any of the role then it is not getting effective until I restart the application. This is because config method of WebsecurityConfigurerAdapter is called only once.

My question here is how can I update the security configuration when my permissions are updated for any role without restarting my application.

Thanks in advance

I cannot upgrade my spring boot version to use SecurityFilterChain. So tried to add filter. But i am unable to get the role of the current user in that filter request. I am getting only the current user details